# Network connection reset after intensive operation

Tags: networking, tcp, ethernet

I am doing a measurement project where I send and receive data from numerous devices on my network. The send/receive can be considered fast and intensive, as there is almost no pause and a continuous flow of data. However, the data to/from each device is quite small, on the order of a couple of bytes each. For some reason, I am experiencing a reset of my entire ethernet connection where my internet connection also goes down, and I lose connection to all my devices as well. I have never experienced such a situation and am wondering what are some of the common situations that might lead to resets like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out this had to do with the way I constructed my thread, in which I would create a new socket continuously without discarding the previous one. Stupid right? Well I fixed the code and the ethernet no longer crashes.